# SoapUI test web service provider

Tags: eclipse

I just downloaded SoapUI and started testing from a local WSDL-file. When I try to run a test, it says "UnknownHostException".

When they ask for the WSDL-file, I don't give a URL but I just select the WSDL-file from my filesystem. Is this wrong? And if so, how/where do I get the right URL to this WSDL-file?

Answer (score 0):

Look into where the endpoint of your services is taking you.

Here are some good links for the starting 
http://www.soapui.org/getting-started/your-first-soapui-project.html
http://www.soapui.org/getting-started/10-tips-for-the-soapui-beginner.html
http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/reference/wsdl-interface.html

Comment: Here is how my SoapUI test properties look like: http://puu.sh/jjen7/30fc30f184.png.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot see this because my DNS doesn't resolve the domain. Any chance you can post it somewhere else?